# How long can a ioredis connection be re-used

Tags: azure, stackexchange.redis, ioredis, socket.io-redis

I am using ioredis to create a redis client in Node for an appservice that is deployed in Azure. The code looks something like this, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M825T.png)

I am creating one connection per instance which will live forever until there is a problem during which it will try to re-connect. I am trying to understand if there is any idle timeout configuration in ioredis that will close these connections.

I am using ioredis to create a redis client in Node for an appservice that is deployed in Azure. The code looks something like this, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M825T.png)

I am creating one connection per instance which will live forever until there is a problem during which it will try to re-connect. I am trying to understand if there is any idle timeout configuration in ioredis that will close these connections. As per the microsoft documentation here,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WQrA.png) some client libraries send a ping to keep the connection open, I am not sure if ioredis is one of them